# Field Proof on mod 3

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

I've a question about my proof of GF(3)[x] for $x^2$+x+2 is a field.

I wanted to prove it as followed:
$$
x(1) = 1\\
x(2) = 2\\
x(3) = 0 \to \text{found the 0-Value of the function}\\
x^2+x+2 / (x-3) = x-2
$$
rest = $0 \implies v(x-3) * v^{-1}(x-2) \implies \text{commutative}$

Is it correct like this? Or do I need to prove it differently?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What are you talking about? Do you want to prove that $\mathbf{F}_3[X]/(X^5+X+2)$ is a field?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to prove that it's a field

Comment: @Default have you ever done a similar problem? You have to show that $X^5+X+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{F}_3[X]$. In any case, "$3$" is not a root $3^5+3+2=0^5+0+2=2\neq 0$ in $\mathbf{F}_3$..

Comment: I don't understand what you do: you first write a quintic, then in you write about $\;0\,-$ value (?), but the quintic you wrote does **not** vanish at $\;x=3\;$ ...

Comment: It's the first time I've to prove a field...So why can I not use 3 for the function?